# Neo4j: Cypher query to parallelize a row of the result from a previous query

Tags: neo4j, parallel-processing, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have a database where sentences are related to each other. I have to perform a big update on the whole database, thus I'm trying to parallelize the update.

The relevant cypher query looks like this:

```
match (s:Sentence)-[r:RELATED]-(t:Sentence)
return s as sentence, collect(t.embedding) as neighbours_embeddings
```

`embedding` is a list of numbers.

This returns a result like this:

```
---------------------------------------
| sentence   |  neighbours_embeddings |
---------------------------------------
| sentence1  | [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] | 
---------------------------------------
| sentence2  | [[2, 3, 5]]            |
---------------------------------------
```

Now I wanna perform some operations on the neighbours_embeddings and set a property in the corresponding Sentence node.

I've looked at different parallelization techniques in Neo4j and as far as I understood, all of them need a list as input. But my input would be a tuple like (sentence, neighbours_embeddings). How do I achieve this?

Full query for interested folks:

```
match (s:Sentence)-[r:RELATED]-(t:Sentence)
with s as sentence, collect(t.embedding) as neighbours
with sentence, [
    w in reduce(s=[], neighbour IN neighbours | 
    case when size(s) = 0 then
    neighbour else [
        i in range(0, size(s)-1) |
        s[i] + neighbour[i]] end) |
        w / tofloat(size(neighbours))
    ] as average
 
 with sentence, [
     i in range(0, size(sentence.embedding)-1) |
     (0.8 * sentence.embedding[i]) + (0.2 *average[i])
 ] as unnormalized
 
 with sentence, unnormalized, sqrt(reduce(sum = 0.0, element in unnormalized | sum + element^2)) as divideby
 set sentence.normalized = [
     i in range(0, size(unnormalized)-1) | (unnormalized[i] / divideby)
 ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For paralelizing, apoc is your friend, specifically the `apoc.periodic.iterate` procedure. In your usecase you can parallelize as you are only updating a property of a single node in each row.

The resulted query would look something like:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate("
match (s:Sentence) RETURN s",
"
match (s)-[r:RELATED]-(t:Sentence)
with s as sentence, collect(t.embedding) as neighbours
with sentence, [
    w in reduce(s=[], neighbour IN neighbours | 
    case when size(s) = 0 then
    neighbour else [
        i in range(0, size(s)-1) |
        s[i] + neighbour[i]] end) |
        w / tofloat(size(neighbours))
    ] as average
 
 with sentence, [
     i in range(0, size(sentence.embedding)-1) |
     (0.8 * sentence.embedding[i]) + (0.2 *average[i])
 ] as unnormalized
 
 with sentence, unnormalized, sqrt(reduce(sum = 0.0, element in unnormalized | sum + element^2)) as divideby
 set sentence.normalized = [
     i in range(0, size(unnormalized)-1) | (unnormalized[i] / divideby)
 ]", {batchSize:1000, parallel:true})
```

You can play around with the batchSize parameter. For more information look at the [docs](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/overview/apoc.periodic/apoc.periodic.iterate/).